# How can I display each object selection I'm doing using guilayout.toggle?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The script is EditorWindow type.

```
private void OnGUI()
{
    if (Selection.objects.OfType<GameObject>().Count() > 0)
            {
                var sel = Selection.objects.OfType<GameObject>().ToList();
                List<GUILayout.Toggle(false, "")> toggles = new List<GUILayout.Toggle(false, "");

                for (int i = 0; i < sel.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (!sel.Contains(sel[i]))
                        GUILayout.Toggle(false, sel[i].name);
                }
            }
}
```

What I want to do is when selection each time a new gameobject in the hierarchy add the selected object to a list and update and display the list with a toggle near the selected object.

Somehow I want to display a List of the selected objects.

Answer (score 0):

Working solution:

```
var selecti = Selection.objects.OfType<GameObject>().ToList();
        if (selecti.Count > 0)
        {
            for (var i = selecti.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
            {
                var selected = selecti[i];
                GUILayout.Toggle(false, selected.name);
            }

            selecti = new List<GameObject>();
        }
```